# Getting difference in response when calling salesforce standard REST api and when querying the same through Custom REST apex

Tags: salesforce

when I query salesforce REST `API (/services/data/v29.0/query?q=select+id,Name,AccountNumber,OwnerId,Site,Description,NumberOfEmployees,Fax,Industry,Phone,Website,Type+from+Account+where+id='0019000000NMrbv')`
I get below response.

```
{
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Account",
      "url" : "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/0019000000NMrbvAAD"
    },
    "Id" : "0019000000NMrbvAAD",
    "Name" : "Test G",
    "AccountNumber" : null,
    "OwnerId" : "00590000001BpGnAAK",
    "Site" : null,
    "Description" : null,
    "NumberOfEmployees" : null,
    "Fax" : null,
    "Industry" : null,
    "Phone" : null,
    "Website" : null,
    "Type" : null
}
```

Now I created an apex rest service like below with same above query

```
@HttpGet
 global static Account doGet(){
    Account acc = [select id,Name,AccountNumber,OwnerId,Site,Description,NumberOfEmployees,Fax,Industry,Phone,Website,Type from Account where id ='0019000000NMrbvAAD'];
    return acc;
}
```

And the response I am getting when I call this service is

```
{
   "attributes":    {
      "type": "Account",
      "url": "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/0019000000NMrbvAAD"
   },
   "Name": "Test G",
   "OwnerId": "00590000001BpGnAAK",
   "Id": "0019000000NMrbvAAD"
}
```

Now please compare the above 2 reponse.The Response from apex rest service does not have the fields which have the null value.

We have created a salesforce ios native app. This service is using the standard REST api, but due to performncce issue we are planning to create APEX rest service,
but due to this difference in response, we will have to change the code at many places to handle this.

Has any one faced such issue and it will be helpful if you suggest how to handle this? Can we do something, so that apex rest service returns the same response 
as by the standard saleforce REST api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've noticed similar behavior in Salesforce's serialization.  Null objects are often simply not included.

It could be the API uses its own serializer.

Regardless, you're not alone.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13820/json-serialize-method-not-returning-null-fields-part-deux